# Capturar resultado de comando SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estoy trabajando en un procedimiento almacenado que reciba como parámetro un nvarchar que seria un comando de sql y necesito que aparte de ejecutarlo (cosa que ya tengo) capture el resultado de ese comando para luego guardarlo en una tabla

ejemplo:

si mi parámetro es

> delete from MyTabla

y en MyTabla hay 5 registros, lo que quiero es guardar en una variable este resultado:

> (5 filas afectadas)

que es el que se mostraría si ejecutara directamente desde el sql. Le he dado varias vueltas y no resuelvo el como, seria de gran ayuda, muchas gracias

Comment: lo quieres obtener en el SQL, o en algun código backend (C# JAVA,VB, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Buenas tardes tocayo puedes hacerlo con:

```
@@ROWCOUNT
```

**referencia:**
[ROWCOUNT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/rowcount-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

Answer (score 0):

Lo más sencillo sería capturar el valor de @@ROWCOUNT

```
DECLARE @FilasAfectadas int;
delete from MyTabla;
SET @FilasAfectadas = @@ROWCOUNT;
```

Ten cuidado, ya que el valor puede ser afectado por triggers.
Otra opción es utilizar la clausula OUTPUT que guardará las filas afectadas en cualquier instrucción DML.